# Spring boot unit test are not running

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I have tried many solution to fix this problem. But no luck My test cases are not running.

[image: My Test directory is like this]

When i did the **mvn clean package**, it is running single test case.
[image: Build result]

> Service layer test

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class OrderStatusServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private OrderStatusServiceImpl orderStatusService;

    @MockBean
    private OrderStatusRepository orderStatusRepository;

    @Before
    public void initialize(){
        orderStatusService = new OrderStatusServiceImpl(orderStatusRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveOrderDetail(){
        OrderDetail orderDetail = getOrderInformation();

        Mockito.when(orderStatusRepository.save(orderDetail)).thenReturn(orderDetail);

        Assert.assertEquals(orderStatusService.addOrderDetail(orderDetail), orderDetail);
    }

    @Test
    public void getOrderDetail(){
        OrderDetail orderDetail = getOrderInformation();

        Mockito.when(orderStatusRepository.findByUserId("abc123")).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(orderDetail));
        Assert.assertEquals(orderStatusService.getOrderDetail("abc123"), java.util.Optional.of(orderDetail));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of the tests? Probably you're missing some annotations

Comment: @MarcusHeld sure i will add

Comment: i can't add whole code, so added service layer unit test

Comment: Looks good for me. Is `mvn test` producing the same result? And do the test run in your IDE?

Comment: @MarcusHeld yes, `mvn test` producing same result. When i run each test in IDE it is fine.

Comment: can you provide your maven pom file?

Comment: @camtastic i have fixed this by modifying the pom file i will write the answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was with pom file.

Maven file while getting the error.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

What i did is removed the exclusion and Junit additional dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```